# How to change a column to use ranges like 1 to 999 instant of id's like, 1 going downwards in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table node. I want the same id numbers of that particular nodetype to be in the same range for example 1 to 9999 and another nodetype to be in another range from 1000 to 1999. Can you give me an example of how to do this. This is a SQL query.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the table looks like eg.schema and data. Also how should the results look like after the query you are looking for is run?

Comment: I cannot attach screen dumps here, but I have a nodede_id column which has 170999000, 172677777, 177333335 id for example, I want the 170999000 to have a range of 1 to 999 and 172677777 a range 1000 to 1999 etc so that a certai type of node belong to a certain range. I'm new to SQL

Comment: So will range be a varchar  with value '1 to 999' for nodede_id 170999000 is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (NODEDE_ID BIGINT)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(170999000),
(172677777),
(177333335)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT NODEDE_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NODEDE_ID) [ROW_NUM]
    FROM @T
)
SELECT NODEDE_ID,
CAST(CASE WHEN (ROW_NUM > 1)
          THEN (ROW_NUM - 1) * 1000
          ELSE 1 
      END AS VARCHAR) + ' to ' +
CAST(CASE WHEN (ROW_NUM > 1)
          THEN ((ROW_NUM - 1) * 1000) + 999
          ELSE 999 
      END AS VARCHAR) [RANGE]
FROM CTE
```